# Azure Dspace 7.6 Circular reference

Tags: spring, tomcat, dspace

I'm trying to install 7.6 on Azure Ubuntu 20 and we completed the installation steps for the back-end.
We make a curl call to check the web application at tomcat and we are getting the following error:

```
Circular placeholder reference 'dspace.dir' in property definition
```

We have checked the answer [DSpace 7.2 with Tomcat 9.0 - Circular placeholder reference 'dspace.dir' in property definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71712261/dspace-7-2-with-tomcat-9-0-circular-placeholder-reference-dspace-dir-in-prop)

At /tomcat/

but we already have set the dspace.dir = /dspace on our local.cfg file.

UPDATE:
I have found a solution but I am not sure it is correct:

At file:

/webapps/server/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties

There is a property
dspace.dir=${dspace.dir} and by changing it to dspace.dir=/dspace the application starts.

My objection is that this file is generated by "and fresh-install".

Shouldn't this file be generated with correct properties?

Is it something else  wrong that I can not see?

Thanks in advance.